# Why is Exiftool slow, memory hog reading from stdin; fast, small reading from disk

Tags: python, amazon-s3, stdin, exiftool

I'm calling exiftool to extract XMP tags like Description from large videos, 5GB and over. My application is Python and I have seen some files which exhaust memory; I invoke it like:

```
fp = open('9502_UAS_2.mov', 'rb')
CMD = 'exiftool -api largefilesupport=1 -sort -a -S -G -struct -j -'
exiftool = subprocess.Popen(CMD.split(),
                            stdin=fp, 
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                            stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
(json_bytes, stderr) = exiftool.communicate()
```

To isolate the problem, I've tried variants on the CLI. This shows that reading from a file on disk is fast and uses little RAM, while reading from STDIN (re-creating the file pointer read above) is very slow and uses a lot of RAM (I've removed the output JSON metadata below for clarity):

```
time exiftool -api largefilesupport=1 -sort -a -S -G -struct -j 9502_UAS.mov
real    0m0.196s

time cat 9502_UAS.mov | exiftool -api largefilesupport=1 -sort -a -S -G -struct -j -
real    0m33.514s
```

'top' showed the second one consumed up to 1.4GB RAM on this 5.1GB video file.

I'd like to understand why reading from STDIN is slow and consumes so much memory, so I can watch out for limits like memory exhaustion on my servers.  Is exiftool reading sequentially through the entire STDIN stream buffering the file until it gets the binary info it needs to parse the metadata? Is it not seek()-ing back and forward to find what it needs?

Conversely, why is running it against a native disk file so quick? Is exiftool using a memory mapped filesystem to quickly jump to the sections of the file it needs to parse?

Ideally, I'd read from STDIN because the real application's file origin is an AWS S3 bucket and I don't want to copy the file to local AWS EC2 disk if I can avoid it, so any hints to make reading stdin efficient would help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you are passing the whole content to `stdin` in the example. This takes time, of course. It would be better to pass the *file name* to the external tool:

```
CMD = 'exiftool -api largefilesupport=1 -sort -a -S -G -struct -j {}'
exiftool = subprocess.Popen(CMD.format('9502_UAS_2.mov').split(),
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                            stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
json_bytes, stderr = exiftool.communicate()
```

When passing to `stdin`, first the whole file will be piped to the program, and only after this process is done, does the process stop (regardless of the tool having done its job already).

When the file is on a remote server, you either need to run this script on that server, copy the file to a local file, or read in the first `n` bytes of the file and pass only these to the exiftool. (Determining how large `n` has to be left as an exercise...)

Comment: I was hoping exiftool could use seek() to jump to the portions of the file it needed then close() when done: apparently not.

I had to use the workaround of copying the file from AWS S3 to AWS EC2 instance which is slow and requires me to use a very large disk partition on the instance since it's not possible to read from the file stream; basically as you show, Popen() reads from the locally-copied file. 

If reading from stdin via stream is not seek/close()-able, it would be nice if exiftool grew an ability to to byte-range reads over HTTP like MediaInfo and  ffmpeg appear to do now.